# Why can't my carpenter's workshop find any wood?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I chopped down some trees a while ago and set up a wood stockpile outside my fortress. The stockpile was filled up as expected. I then build a carpentry workshop on z-level below and assigned it to make 3 wheelbarrows. The tasks where canceled because it could not find any logs. But I clearly have logs - both outside on the ground and in the stockpile. So why won't it make the wheelbarrow? The same is true with barrels.

Moreover, I made a need wood stockpile right next to it and the dwarfs are not moving anything into it. The wood is not forbidden or dumped, I don't think I have any links set up, I didn't build any barrows, and my dwarfs have standing orders to gather wood. I uploaded my save [here](http://dffd.wimbli.com/file.php?id=10054).

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can dwarves access the workshop? It sounds like you've accidentally removed some stairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look at the contents of the save file shows that you did indeed accidentally remove some stairs (as was suggested in Studoku's comment). There are three types of stairs in the game, *up* stairs "<", *down* stairs ">", and *up/down* stairs, "X". (Note that these symbols are the default without any graphical mods, the way I run the game and the appearance that most instructions I have seen reference.) *up/down* stairs count as both *up* and *down* stairs existing in the tile. For a dwarf to travel between two tiles that are supposed to be connected by stairs, there must be a *down* stair in the upper tile AND an *up* stair in the lower tile. Your fortress has just down stairs present. Either you dug only down stairs, using the **j** command in the designations menu or you accidentally removed the up portion of the stairs using the **z** command in said menu. In order to dig *up/down* stairs you should use the **i** command in said menu (you may still want *down* stairs at the top floor and *up* stairs at the bottom). Unfortunately there is no way to dig *down* stairs into *up/down* stairs. I would suggest digging a new stairway off to one side for now. You can build *up/down* stairs as a construction later.

I hope that this explanation is useful. The short version is that your stairs aren't connecting right and you should dig a completely new stairway using the **i** designation rather than the **j** designation. For even more detail the appropriate wiki article is [Stairs](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Stairs).

Comment: I'm trying to put an up stair case into the lower level, but its not working for some reason. I select a 1x1 square one tile under the center of my 3x3 staircase, but when I press enter no marker for building construction is placed. Why is that?

Comment: nevermind, I managed to get it working using the `b->C` command. But why does that one work, while the `d` comamnd doesnt?

Comment: `d` works for digging stairs out of dirt. If you already dug out the square, you have to `b`uild them as a building. instead.